# Extension to offer link to The Wayback Machine?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox

Suppose I click any linked resource and I end up with this:

[image]

... or this:

[image]

... but to me as a user it's obvious that this resource may have once existed, I'd like an extension that changes the above to include a link (preferably configurable) to The Wayback Machine. That is, if I visit a URL described by placeholder `$URL` I'd like the above error pages to give me a link to one or several (at my discretion!) cached alternatives.

That is to `https://web.archive.org/web/*/$URL` for The Wayback Machine.

Is there such an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the Firefox or Chrome extension, Wayback Machine. It is from Internet Archive (Archive.org). It claims to "Reduce annoying 404 pages by automatically checking for an archived copy in the Wayback Machine."

Firefox Extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/wayback-machine_new/

Chrome Extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/nbkhjdgdpjdebcniehkeigmdfeiokegh

Answer (score 0):

I have meanwhile found an alternative for Firefox for the Wayback Machine extension (available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/wayback-machine_new/) *and* [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/nbkhjdgdpjdebcniehkeigmdfeiokegh)). It's called [Web Archives](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/view-page-archive/) (also [available for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-archives/hkligngkgcpcolhcnkgccglchdafcnao)).

Its description reads:

> View archived and cached versions of web pages on 10+ search engines,
> such as the Wayback Machine, Archive.is, Google, Bing, Yandex,
> Gigablast, WebCite, Sogou, Memento, Naver and Yahoo Japan.

It looks like this:

[image: Web Archives]

Just like the suggested extension(s) it doesn't do it exactly the way I want, but it's a helper nevertheless.